# NA: Detected: Filling NA's with zeros

Tags: r, debugging, warnings, nas

When running my code to debug, I get a Warning Message to fill NA's with Zeros. Though I don't want to touch so much in this part of the code because it gives information to the whole project.

line 72: offensive <- EAA(prices, cashAsset="VBMFX", bestN=3)

> Warning messages:
> 1: In Return.rebalancing(R = returns, weights = weights) :
> NA's detected: filling NA's with zeros

> 2: In Return.portfolio.geometric(R = R, weights = weights, wealth.index = wealth.index,  :
> The weights for one or more periods do not sum up to 1: assuming a return of 0 for the residual weights

I'm so lost on what to do in this part. It's literally the last bug to my entire project.

Comment: Hello, just a question, has your dataset `NA`s?

Comment: Not understanding what you're trying to ask.